# In Flutter, how to get the time of different time zones using DateTime?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, widget

How to achieve the times of different time zones using the DateTime in Flutter

Comment: Try [`package:timezone`](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone).

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` does not contain info on the timezone therefore you can't create a `DateTime` in a specific timezone. Only the timezone of your system and UTC are available.

You could use a package such as https://pub.dev/packages/timezone or search for similar ones on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)